# Почему внутри Vue файла (компонента) недоступен функционал Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Имеется SPA, основанное на Vue (Vuex).

Есть компонент Login. Внутри форма с двумя полями - email и password - они также прописаны в `data()`, а у полей формы добавлены `v-model`. Изменения сохраняются в `data()`.

```
data: () => ({
  local: {
    form: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }
}),
```

Проблема в том, что если написать этот код:

```
created: () => {
  console.log(this)
},
```

То я получаю это в консоли браузера: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bAFf.png

То есть мне недоступно ни Vuex хранилище, ни Apollo, ни что-либо другое. Даже банальный доступ к `data()` из кода не могу получить.

Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: так this - это ж компонент, он вроде как и вывелся.

Comment: @Grundy а как мне получить доступ к `Vue` и всему что было инициализировано в файле `main.js`? Просто во всех документациях прописано одно и то же - например, `this.$apollo`, `this.$http` и так далее. А я даже доступ к `data()` получить не могу...

Comment: @Grundy Опять же конкретный пример - https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo-todos/blob/master/src/components/TodoCreate.vue . На этой странице найдите 54 строку. У меня это не работает...

Comment: а ты пробовал этот код? или только в консоль браузера смотрел?

Comment: @Grundy да, я пытаюсь отправить мутацию. Безуспешно - `undefined`.

Comment: @Grundy `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.$apollo.mutate')`

Comment: сделай [mcve] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема возникала из-за такого вида методов:

```
data: () => ({ ... })
```

Надо было везде писать просто:

```
data() { ... }
```

Или

```
onSubmit() { ... }
```